# Symbology Displays Incorrectly When Sharing Service to ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology, arcgis-online, feature-service

Some of my symbols are displaying incorrectly in AGOL. This is a new problem - yesterday they displayed fine and suddenly they are coming in, for lack of a better word, garbled. This is a street sign layer in ArcGIS, and a few of the sign classes display poorly online, but look just fine in ArcGIS Desktop (see attached images - looking in particular at the yellow left turn sign, roughly centered).

Things I've tried to do to fix the problem: remove and re-add the AGOL layer. Reapply in ArcGIS the symbology from the layer file I originally used to symbolize. Re-share the .mxd as map and feature service to my ArcGIS Server site.

Between each troubleshooting idea I've cleared my browser cache as well.

[image]
ArcGIS Desktop

[image]
ArcGIS Online